# How to map over an array of multiple objects for graphing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chartist.js, react-chartist

I have an API response that provides multiple objects in an array:

```
[{"symbol":"AAPL","date":"2020-02-27","adj_close":68.24}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"2020-02-27","adj_close":133.8}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"2020-02-28","adj_close":122.3}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"2020-02-28","adj_close":64.09}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"2020-03-02","adj_close":137.33}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"2020-03-02","adj_close":69.43}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"2020-03-03","adj_close":143.22},
  ...
]
```

I'm trying to create a map() that graphs each unique `symbol` from the response, for each `<card>` that already maps through another array of data. Like so:

[image]
But as you can see, the mapping function I've made for my graphs does not work. It's stacking all of the data for each unique `symbol` onto each card. I would like each unique symbol to have it's own data graphed.
I haven't been able to succeed, I have made a reproducible code below:

reproduceable code:https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-curie-5qck3?file=/src/index.js

Here is how I set up everything:

**Parents.js**

```
export function MiniGraphDisplay(props)
{
    const { data } = props;
    const { slug } = useParams();
    const [historicalPrice, setHistoricalPrice] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = useCallback(async () =>
    {
        const response = await axiosInstance.get('bucket/graph-price/' + slug)
        const result = response.data;
        setHistoricalPrice(result);
    }, [])

    useEffect(() =>
    {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
        <Container maxWidth="lg" component="main">
            <Grid container spacing={5} alignItems="flex-end">
                {data[0]?.map((data,index) => {
                    return (
                        <Grid item key={index} xs={4} md={4}>
                            <Card>
                            <CardHeader
                            title={<Chip label={data.symbol} />} 
                            subheader={data.adj_close}        
                            />      
                            <CardContent >
                                <div>
                                <MiniGraphs historicalPrice={historicalPrice} />
                                </div>              
                            </CardContent>
                            </Card>
                        </Grid>
                    );
                })}
            </Grid>
        </Container>
        </>
    );
}
```

**Child.js**

```
export function MiniGraphs(props)
{
  const { historicalPrice } = props;

  const getChartData = () =>
  {
    const labels = [];
    const series = [];

    historicalPrice.forEach((item,) =>
    {
      labels.push(item.date);
      series.push(item.adj_close);
    });

    return {
      labels: labels,
      series: [series]
    };
  };

  // Add graph configuration here
  const chartOptions = {
    // width: 2000,
    height: 200,
    // scaleMinSpace: 20
    onlyInteger: true,
    showPoint: false,
    axisX: {
      labelInterpolationFnc: function (value, index)
      {
        return index % 32 === 0 ? value : null;
      },
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      { historicalPrice && <ChartistGraph data={getChartData()} options={chartOptions} type="Line" />}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just working off your Sandbox here. The first thing to fix, it appears, is to only pass the relevant data to your `MiniGraphs` component. That can be done by:

```
...
<CardContent>
  <div>
    <MiniGraphs
      historicalPrice={response.filter(
      (i) => i.symbol === data.symbol
      )}
    />
  </div>
</CardContent>
...
```

The other thing you seem to be missing, at least in your Sandbox, is proper styling for your graphs. So I added the contents of this file `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.11.4/chartist.min.css` to the `styles.css` files in the Sandbox.

The result seems to be what you're looking for: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-https-tol8c?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try and
here a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-jepsen-4wcbw?autoresize=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=preview)

```js
<MiniGraphs symbol={data.symbol} historicalPrice={response} />
```

and for filtering data

```
const { historicalPrice, symbol } = props;

  const filterBySymbol = (symbol, key) =>
    historicalPrice
      .filter((elm) => elm.symbol === symbol)
      .map((elm) => elm[key]);


  const mapper = {
    labels: filterBySymbol(symbol, "date"),
    series: [filterBySymbol(symbol, "adj_close")]
  };
...

<ChartistGraph data={mapper} ...
```